# View doesn't perform, but running the same query directly does

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, azure-sql-database

For PowerBI Usage we have a view on our biggest table. However, it will not run, timing out with *PAGEIOLATCH_SH*. The Query is as simple as:

`select * from view where ProgramId = 'ParticularProgram'`

However, if we run the query within the view, it works without any issues or time-outs. Do you know what could cause this? The original query in the view is:

`select column 1, column 2 etc from table where ProgramId = 'ParticularProgram'`

Specifying a where clause with the partition does not change the behaviour and keeps it slow. Query cost of the first one is 99%, when both are ran together. The ProgramId is partitioned in the table, and this Particular Program is part of that Partition.

Many thanks in advance

Please find Attached the Actual query plan for the query that is working:
[DirectQueryOnTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GHZx.png), the XML [DirextQueryExecutionPlanXML](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1c5SOXeU) and the corresponding ddl:

```
/****** Object:  Table [dm].[AggProgramPeriodLoyalty]    Script Date: 1/8/2020 3:47:03 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dm].[AggProgramPeriodLoyalty](
    [AggProgramPeriodLoyaltyKey] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ProgramId] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [ProgramTitle] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [ProgramCurrency] [nvarchar](3) NULL,
    [ProgramPeriodType] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ProgramPeriodTypeLabel] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [IsCurrentProgramPeriod] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [IsLastCompletedProgramPeriod] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [LoyaltyId] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [IsRegistered] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IsRegisteredCml] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UsedPlatforms] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [DigitalStampsBalanceMutation] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DigitalStampsBalance] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DigitalRedeemPotential] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DigitalParticipationBonusInteractions] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DigitalParticipationBonusInteractionsCml] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DigitalParticipationBonusStamps] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DigitalParticipationBonusStampsCml] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DigitalCollectInteractions] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DigitalCollectInteractionsCml] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IsNewDigitalCollector] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IsDigitalCollector] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IsDigitalCollectorCml] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DigitalCollectedStamps] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DigitalCollectedStampsCml] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TurnoverByDigitalCollectors] [decimal](18, 5) NOT NULL,
    [TurnoverByDigitalCollectorsCml] [decimal](18, 5) NOT NULL,
    [DigitalRedeemInteractions] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DigitalRedeemInteractionsCml] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IsNewDigitalRedeemer] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IsDigitalRedeemer] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IsDigitalRedeemerCml] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DigitalRedeemedStamps] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DigitalRedeemedStampsCml] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DigitalRewards] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DigitalRewardsCml] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TurnoverByDigitalRedeemers] [decimal](18, 5) NOT NULL,
    [TurnoverByDigitalRedeemersCml] [decimal](18, 5) NOT NULL,
    [AdditionalPaymentForDigitalRewards] [decimal](18, 5) NOT NULL,
    [AdditionalPaymentForDigitalRewardsCml] [decimal](18, 5) NOT NULL,
    [DigitalCounterRedeemInteractions] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DigitalCounterRedeemInteractionsCml] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DigitalConvertInteractions] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DigitalConvertInteractionsCml] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DigitalConvertedStamps] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DigitalConvertedStampsCml] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DigitalAddInteractions] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DigitalAddInteractionsCml] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DigitalAddedStamps] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DigitalAddedStampsCml] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DigitalDeductInteractions] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DigitalDeductInteractionsCml] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DigitalDeductedStamps] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DigitalDeductedStampsCml] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DigitalTransferToInteractions] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DigitalTransferToInteractionsCml] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DigitalTransferedToStamps] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DigitalTransferedToStampsCml] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DigitalTransferFromInteractions] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DigitalTransferFromInteractionsCml] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DigitalTransferedFromStamps] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DigitalTransferedFromStampsCml] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DigitalGiftCreatedInteractions] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DigitalGiftCreatedInteractionsCml] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DigitalGiftCreatedStamps] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DigitalGiftCreatedStampsCml] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DigitalGiftRedeemedInteractions] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DigitalGiftRedeemedInteractionsCml] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DigitalGiftRedeemedStamps] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DigitalGiftRedeemedStampsCml] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DigitalGiftExpiredInteractions] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DigitalGiftExpiredInteractionsCml] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DigitalGiftExpiredStamps] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DigitalGiftExpiredStampsCml] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DigitalGiftCancelledInteractions] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DigitalGiftCancelledInteractionsCml] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DigitalGiftCancelledStamps] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DigitalGiftCancelledStampsCml] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CreateDTS] [datetime2](3) NOT NULL,
    [CreateExnId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UpdateDTS] [datetime2](3) NULL,
    [UpdateExnId] [int] NULL,
    [IsProfileCompleted] [int] NULL,
    [IsProfileCompletedCml] [int] NULL,
    [DigitalRedeemBonusInteractions] [int] NULL,
    [DigitalRedeemBonusInteractionsCml] [int] NULL,
    [DigitalRedeemBonusStamps] [int] NULL,
    [DigitalRedeemBonusStampsCml] [int] NULL,
    [DigitalCounterCollectInteractions] [int] NULL,
    [DigitalCounterCollectInteractionsCml] [int] NULL,
    [DigitalCounterRedeemBonusInteractions] [int] NULL,
    [DigitalCounterRedeemBonusInteractionsCml] [int] NULL,
    [ProgramWeekCombination] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [TotalUsedPlatforms] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_AggProgramPeriodLoyalty] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [AggProgramPeriodLoyaltyKey] ASC,
    [ProgramId] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PS_ByProgramId]([ProgramId]),
 CONSTRAINT [UK_AggProgramPeriodLoyalty] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [ProgramId] ASC,
    [ProgramPeriodType] ASC,
    [LoyaltyId] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PS_ByProgramId]([ProgramId])
) ON [PS_ByProgramId]([ProgramId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dm].[AggProgramPeriodLoyalty] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [DigitalGiftCreatedInteractions]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dm].[AggProgramPeriodLoyalty] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [DigitalGiftCreatedInteractionsCml]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dm].[AggProgramPeriodLoyalty] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [DigitalGiftCreatedStamps]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dm].[AggProgramPeriodLoyalty] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [DigitalGiftCreatedStampsCml]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dm].[AggProgramPeriodLoyalty] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [DigitalGiftRedeemedInteractions]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dm].[AggProgramPeriodLoyalty] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [DigitalGiftRedeemedInteractionsCml]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dm].[AggProgramPeriodLoyalty] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [DigitalGiftRedeemedStamps]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dm].[AggProgramPeriodLoyalty] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [DigitalGiftRedeemedStampsCml]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dm].[AggProgramPeriodLoyalty] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [DigitalGiftExpiredInteractions]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dm].[AggProgramPeriodLoyalty] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [DigitalGiftExpiredInteractionsCml]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dm].[AggProgramPeriodLoyalty] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [DigitalGiftExpiredStamps]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dm].[AggProgramPeriodLoyalty] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [DigitalGiftExpiredStampsCml]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dm].[AggProgramPeriodLoyalty] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [DigitalGiftCancelledInteractions]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dm].[AggProgramPeriodLoyalty] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [DigitalGiftCancelledInteractionsCml]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dm].[AggProgramPeriodLoyalty] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [DigitalGiftCancelledStamps]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dm].[AggProgramPeriodLoyalty] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [DigitalGiftCancelledStampsCml]
GO
```

And the estimated query plan for the select statement on the view, that is not performing at all: [QueryOnView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfThH.png), the XML [ViewExecutionPlanXML](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ByU4rd7gL)

And the view DDL:

```
CREATE view [dm].[vwAggProgramPeriodLoyalty]
as
select [AggProgramPeriodLoyaltyKey] as [Agg Program Period Loyalty Key]
     , upper([ProgramId]) as [Program Id]
     , [ProgramTitle] as [Program Title]
     , [ProgramCurrency] as [Program Currency]
     , [ProgramPeriodType] as [Program Period Type]
     , [ProgramPeriodTypeLabel] as [Program Period Type Label]
     , upper([ProgramWeekCombination]) as [Program Week Combination] 
     , [IsCurrentProgramPeriod] as [Is Current Program Period]
     , [IsLastCompletedProgramPeriod] as [Is Last Completed Program Period]
     , [LoyaltyId] as [Loyalty Id]
     , [IsRegistered] as [Is Registered]
     , [IsRegisteredCml] as [Is Registered Cumulative]
     , [UsedPlatforms] as [Used Platforms]
     , [DigitalStampsBalanceMutation] as [Digital Stamps Balance Mutation]
     , [DigitalStampsBalance] as [Digital Stamps Balance]
     , [DigitalRedeemPotential] as [Digital Redeem Potential]
     , [DigitalParticipationBonusInteractions] as [Digital Participation Bonus Interactions]
     , [DigitalParticipationBonusInteractionsCml] as [Digital Participation Bonus Interactions Cumulative]
     , [DigitalParticipationBonusStamps] as [Digital Participation Bonus Stamps]
     , [DigitalParticipationBonusStampsCml] as [Digital Participation Bonus Stamps Cumulative]
     , [DigitalCollectInteractions] as [Digital Collect Interactions]
     , [DigitalCollectInteractionsCml] as [Digital Collect Interactions Cumulative]
     , [IsNewDigitalCollector] as [Is First Digital Collect]
     , [IsDigitalCollector] as [Is Digital Collector]
     , [IsDigitalCollectorCml] as [Is Digital Collector Cumulative]
     , [DigitalCollectedStamps] as [Digital Collected Stamps]
     , [DigitalCollectedStampsCml] as [Digital Collected Stamps Cumulative]
     , [TurnoverByDigitalCollectors] as [Turnover By Digital Collectors]
     , [TurnoverByDigitalCollectorsCml] as [Turnover By Digital Collectors Cumulative]
     , [DigitalRedeemInteractions] as [Digital Redeem Interactions]
     , [DigitalRedeemInteractionsCml] as [Digital Redeem Interactions Cumulative]
     , [IsNewDigitalRedeemer] as [Is First Digital Redeem]
     , [IsDigitalRedeemer] as [Is Digital Redeemer]
     , [IsDigitalRedeemerCml] as [Is Digital Redeemer Cumulative]
     , [DigitalRedeemedStamps] as [Digital Redeemed Stamps]
     , [DigitalRedeemedStampsCml] as [Digital Redeemed Stamps Cumulative]
     , [DigitalRewards] as [Digital Rewards]
     , [DigitalRewardsCml] as [Digital Rewards Cumulative]
     , [TurnoverByDigitalRedeemers] as [Turnover By Digital Redeemers]
     , [TurnoverByDigitalRedeemersCml] as [Turnover By Digital Redeemers Cumulative]
     , [AdditionalPaymentForDigitalRewards] as [Additional Payment For Digital Rewards]
     , [AdditionalPaymentForDigitalRewardsCml] as [Additional Payment For Digital Rewards Cumulative]
     , [DigitalConvertInteractions] as [Digital Convert Interactions]
     , [DigitalConvertInteractionsCml] as [Digital Convert Interactions Cumulative]
     , [DigitalConvertedStamps] as [Digital Converted Stamps]
     , [DigitalConvertedStampsCml] as [Digital Converted Stamps Cumulative]
     , [DigitalAddInteractions] as [Digital Add Interactions]
     , [DigitalAddInteractionsCml] as [Digital Add Interactions Cumulative]
     , [DigitalAddedStamps] as [Digital Added Stamps]
     , [DigitalAddedStampsCml] as [Digital Added Stamps Cumulative]
     , [DigitalDeductInteractions] as [Digital Deduct Interactions]
     , [DigitalDeductInteractionsCml] as [Digital Deduct Interactions Cumulative]
     , [DigitalDeductedStamps] as [Digital Deducted Stamps]
     , [DigitalDeductedStampsCml] as [Digital Deducted Stamps Cumulative]
     , [DigitalTransferToInteractions] as [Digital Transfer To Interactions]
     , [DigitalTransferToInteractionsCml] as [Digital Transfer To Interactions Cumulative]
     , [DigitalTransferedToStamps] as [Digital Transfered To Stamps]
     , [DigitalTransferedToStampsCml] as [Digital Transfered To Stamps Cumulative]
     , [DigitalTransferFromInteractions] as [Digital Transfer From Interactions]
     , [DigitalTransferFromInteractionsCml] as [Digital Transfer From Interactions Cumulative]
     , [DigitalTransferedFromStamps] as [Digital Transfered From Stamps]
     , [DigitalTransferedFromStampsCml] as [Digital Transfered From Stamps Cumulative]
     , [DigitalGiftCreatedInteractions] as [Digital Gift Created Interactions]            
     , [DigitalGiftCreatedInteractionsCml] as [Digital Gift Created Interactions Cumulative]    
     , [DigitalGiftCreatedStamps] as [Digital Gift Created Stamps]             
     , [DigitalGiftCreatedStampsCml] as [Digital Gift Created Stamps Cumulative]            
     , [DigitalGiftRedeemedInteractions] as [Digital Gift Redeemed Interactions]      
     , [DigitalGiftRedeemedInteractionsCml]  as [Digital Gift Redeemed Interactions Cumulative]     
     , [DigitalGiftRedeemedStamps] as [Digital Gift Redeemed Stamps]            
     , [DigitalGiftRedeemedStampsCml] as [Digital Gift Redeemed Stamps Cumulative]      
     , [DigitalGiftExpiredInteractions] as [Digital Gift Expired Interactions]          
     , [DigitalGiftExpiredInteractionsCml] as [Digital Gift Expired Interactions Cumulative]  
     , [DigitalGiftExpiredStamps] as [Digital Gift Expired Stamps]              
     , [DigitalGiftExpiredStampsCml] as [Digital Gift Expired Stamps Cumulative]        
     , [DigitalGiftCancelledInteractions] as [Digital Gift Cancelled Interactions]     
     , [DigitalGiftCancelledInteractionsCml] as [Digital Gift Cancelled Interactions Cumulative]    
     , [DigitalGiftCancelledStamps] as [Digital Gift Cancelled Stamps]           
     , [DigitalGiftCancelledStampsCml] as [Digital Gift Cancelled Stamps Cumulative]
  from [dm].[AggProgramPeriodLoyalty];
```

Furthermore I added an overview of the time-out: [LogOfWaitType](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2ajZ.png)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. As it stands, we can only guess - please post a schema definition (for both your base tables and your view), and the execution plan for both queries.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. I added some information, and would like to add the schema definition as well. Do you mean the table structure and the query used in the view? Or do you mean something different?

Comment: are you using any windowed functions in your query?

Comment: We _much_ prefer text to images, if that's okay! And yes, the DDL for the tables and the view would be great.

Comment: @Bonzay, I now included the DDL. The view does not contain any windowed functions, only 2 uppers. And as far as I am aware this does not affect performance.

Comment: @NevilleKuyt I have 2 xmls, but I cannot upload them without breaching the character limit. Sorry for the inconvenience, I am still quite new to Stack Overflow. Could you please advice on how to proceed with the Query plans in text? I couldnt find much about this online

Comment: @SenneAudier you can paste the XML into Paste the plan - it will generate a unique URL - you can add that URL to this question. https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: in sql server 2005 that i use, when a windowed function such as row number is used in a view and the predicate is placed on the outside of the view the optimizer will scan the base table first, this is why i asked. I am not sure if this happens in later versions although i am not sure which version you use. Your view execution plan shows nothing usefull in my opinion. Maybe it is a cache problem. Try to drop and recreate the view.  You also mention "a where clause with the partition does not change the behaviour and keeps it slow".Is the table partitioned? What's the row count?

Comment: Please can you show your WHERE clauses for the queries

Comment: @SteveFord They are added in the example queries, and should be in the xml as well. It is a where on a partitioned column.

Comment: @Bonzay, Recreating and dropping did not work, but good idea! The table is partitioned on ProgramId. The Rowcount of the entire table is 113 million, while the Program we are selecting on only contains 224k rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view scans the base table first, then applies the filter which is consisted of the partition key. Thus the extreme performance difference. The execution plans are completely different. Since you are not performing anything in your view and only select some of the base table fields, i would recommend to drop the view and use the table directly. Another alternative would be a TVF :

```
    CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_MyWorkaround(@ProgramId VARCHAR(50))
    RETURNS TABLE
    RETURN(
        select [AggProgramPeriodLoyaltyKey] as [Agg Program Period Loyalty Key]
     , upper([ProgramId]) as [Program Id]
     , [ProgramTitle] as [Program Title]
     , [ProgramCurrency] as [Program Currency]
     , [ProgramPeriodType] as [Program Period Type]
     , [ProgramPeriodTypeLabel] as [Program Period Type Label]
     , upper([ProgramWeekCombination]) as [Program Week Combination] 
     , [IsCurrentProgramPeriod] as [Is Current Program Period]
     , [IsLastCompletedProgramPeriod] as [Is Last Completed Program Period]
     , [LoyaltyId] as [Loyalty Id]
     , [IsRegistered] as [Is Registered]
     , [IsRegisteredCml] as [Is Registered Cumulative]
     , [UsedPlatforms] as [Used Platforms]
     , [DigitalStampsBalanceMutation] as [Digital Stamps Balance Mutation]
     , [DigitalStampsBalance] as [Digital Stamps Balance]
     , [DigitalRedeemPotential] as [Digital Redeem Potential]
     , [DigitalParticipationBonusInteractions] as [Digital Participation Bonus Interactions]
     , [DigitalParticipationBonusInteractionsCml] as [Digital Participation Bonus Interactions Cumulative]
     , [DigitalParticipationBonusStamps] as [Digital Participation Bonus Stamps]
     , [DigitalParticipationBonusStampsCml] as [Digital Participation Bonus Stamps Cumulative]
     , [DigitalCollectInteractions] as [Digital Collect Interactions]
     , [DigitalCollectInteractionsCml] as [Digital Collect Interactions Cumulative]
     , [IsNewDigitalCollector] as [Is First Digital Collect]
     , [IsDigitalCollector] as [Is Digital Collector]
     , [IsDigitalCollectorCml] as [Is Digital Collector Cumulative]
     , [DigitalCollectedStamps] as [Digital Collected Stamps]
     , [DigitalCollectedStampsCml] as [Digital Collected Stamps Cumulative]
     , [TurnoverByDigitalCollectors] as [Turnover By Digital Collectors]
     , [TurnoverByDigitalCollectorsCml] as [Turnover By Digital Collectors Cumulative]
     , [DigitalRedeemInteractions] as [Digital Redeem Interactions]
     , [DigitalRedeemInteractionsCml] as [Digital Redeem Interactions Cumulative]
     , [IsNewDigitalRedeemer] as [Is First Digital Redeem]
     , [IsDigitalRedeemer] as [Is Digital Redeemer]
     , [IsDigitalRedeemerCml] as [Is Digital Redeemer Cumulative]
     , [DigitalRedeemedStamps] as [Digital Redeemed Stamps]
     , [DigitalRedeemedStampsCml] as [Digital Redeemed Stamps Cumulative]
     , [DigitalRewards] as [Digital Rewards]
     , [DigitalRewardsCml] as [Digital Rewards Cumulative]
     , [TurnoverByDigitalRedeemers] as [Turnover By Digital Redeemers]
     , [TurnoverByDigitalRedeemersCml] as [Turnover By Digital Redeemers Cumulative]
     , [AdditionalPaymentForDigitalRewards] as [Additional Payment For Digital Rewards]
     , [AdditionalPaymentForDigitalRewardsCml] as [Additional Payment For Digital Rewards Cumulative]
     , [DigitalConvertInteractions] as [Digital Convert Interactions]
     , [DigitalConvertInteractionsCml] as [Digital Convert Interactions Cumulative]
     , [DigitalConvertedStamps] as [Digital Converted Stamps]
     , [DigitalConvertedStampsCml] as [Digital Converted Stamps Cumulative]
     , [DigitalAddInteractions] as [Digital Add Interactions]
     , [DigitalAddInteractionsCml] as [Digital Add Interactions Cumulative]
     , [DigitalAddedStamps] as [Digital Added Stamps]
     , [DigitalAddedStampsCml] as [Digital Added Stamps Cumulative]
     , [DigitalDeductInteractions] as [Digital Deduct Interactions]
     , [DigitalDeductInteractionsCml] as [Digital Deduct Interactions Cumulative]
     , [DigitalDeductedStamps] as [Digital Deducted Stamps]
     , [DigitalDeductedStampsCml] as [Digital Deducted Stamps Cumulative]
     , [DigitalTransferToInteractions] as [Digital Transfer To Interactions]
     , [DigitalTransferToInteractionsCml] as [Digital Transfer To Interactions Cumulative]
     , [DigitalTransferedToStamps] as [Digital Transfered To Stamps]
     , [DigitalTransferedToStampsCml] as [Digital Transfered To Stamps Cumulative]
     , [DigitalTransferFromInteractions] as [Digital Transfer From Interactions]
     , [DigitalTransferFromInteractionsCml] as [Digital Transfer From Interactions Cumulative]
     , [DigitalTransferedFromStamps] as [Digital Transfered From Stamps]
     , [DigitalTransferedFromStampsCml] as [Digital Transfered From Stamps Cumulative]
     , [DigitalGiftCreatedInteractions] as [Digital Gift Created Interactions]            
     , [DigitalGiftCreatedInteractionsCml] as [Digital Gift Created Interactions Cumulative]    
     , [DigitalGiftCreatedStamps] as [Digital Gift Created Stamps]             
     , [DigitalGiftCreatedStampsCml] as [Digital Gift Created Stamps Cumulative]            
     , [DigitalGiftRedeemedInteractions] as [Digital Gift Redeemed Interactions]      
     , [DigitalGiftRedeemedInteractionsCml]  as [Digital Gift Redeemed Interactions Cumulative]     
     , [DigitalGiftRedeemedStamps] as [Digital Gift Redeemed Stamps]            
     , [DigitalGiftRedeemedStampsCml] as [Digital Gift Redeemed Stamps Cumulative]      
     , [DigitalGiftExpiredInteractions] as [Digital Gift Expired Interactions]          
     , [DigitalGiftExpiredInteractionsCml] as [Digital Gift Expired Interactions Cumulative]  
     , [DigitalGiftExpiredStamps] as [Digital Gift Expired Stamps]              
     , [DigitalGiftExpiredStampsCml] as [Digital Gift Expired Stamps Cumulative]        
     , [DigitalGiftCancelledInteractions] as [Digital Gift Cancelled Interactions]     
     , [DigitalGiftCancelledInteractionsCml] as [Digital Gift Cancelled Interactions Cumulative]    
     , [DigitalGiftCancelledStamps] as [Digital Gift Cancelled Stamps]           
     , [DigitalGiftCancelledStampsCml] as [Digital Gift Cancelled Stamps Cumulative]
  from [dm].[AggProgramPeriodLoyalty]
        WHERE ProgramId = @ProgramId
    )
    GO
```

and then run it using :

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.fn_MyWorkaround('ParticularProgram')
```

This will give you the same execution times.

Comment: It indeeds looks like the Scan and sort step at with the View cause the problems. We will indeed start querying directly on the table, to prevent this from happening, as the main function of the view was to add Spaces to the names, which we will now move over to PowerBI. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Two problems that I can see:

- No index on `ProgramId`, so even the table query is slow.
- The view query is actually equivalent to `...where upper(ProgramId) = 'ParticularProgram'`, so even if index on `ProgramId` did exist, it would not be directly usable. See also: [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).

Recommendations:

- Index `ProgramId` (this should speed-up the table query as well).
- Modify the view to include `ProgramId AS [Program Id Original]` and then query on *that* (assuming you don't actually need case insensitivity when using case-sensitive collation):

  `select * from view where [Program Id Original] = 'ParticularProgram'`

Alternatively, create a functional index on `upper(ProgramId)`.

---

Also, look into using case-insensitive collation, so you won't need to use `upper` in the WHERE clause.